# Neo4j - Recursive pattern matching and returning recursive path for specific leaf nodes

Tags: recursion, neo4j, cypher

I have a structure where a node either "Leads_to" another node or is "Colored_in" some color. The "Colored_in" relation and the color are just simplified additional information.

I now want for each leaf node regarding "Leads_to" all information of the parent nodes, as well as their additional information over the "Colored_in" relation.
To simplify this I will give a small sample of what I want:

```
CREATE (A:Key {name:'a'}),
(B:Key {name:'b'}),
(C:Key {name:'c'}),
(D:Key {name:'d'}),
(Black:Color {color:'black'}),
(Blue:Color {color:'blue'}),
(A)-[:Leads_to]->(B),
(A)-[:Leads_to]->(C),
(B)-[:Leads_to]->(D),
(A)-[:Colored_in]->(Black),
(B)-[:Colored_in]->(Blue),
(C)-[:Colored_in]->(Blue),
(D)-[:Colored_in]->(Black)
```

This code will create the following structure:

```
                A-->Black
               / \
              /   \
      Blue<--B     C-->Blue
            /       
           /         
  Black<--D
```

This is just roughly drawn and both "Blue"s and "Black"s refer to the same instance of either "Blue" or "Black".

And as a result I want something like:

```
[{{name:'a',{color:'black'}; name:'b', {color:'blue'}; name:'d',{color:'black'}},
{{name:'a',{color:'black'}; name:'c', {color:'blue'}}]
```

Additionally a color can not "Leads_to" something nor be "Colored_in" something. This is just an example, the real path can be much longer. Also the nested result does not have to be in the format above, the parents just have to be clearly separated from each other (Ex.: ";") and should be in the right order.

Edit:

Maybe it helps, that not all potential information from other relations is required, but just from one relation in this case "Colored_in" and the name is fixed and the properties are known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So maybe something like this?

```
MATCH path = (leaf:Key)-[:Leads_to*]->(end)
WHERE NOT ()-[:Leads_to]->(leaf) AND NOT (end)-[:Leads_to]->()
RETURN [node in nodes(path) | node {.name, color: [(node)-[:Colored_in]->(colorNode) | colorNode.color][0]}] as result
```

This uses list comprehension, map projection, and pattern comprehension so, for each node in each matched path, it outputs a custom map of the node name, and the color of the node's attached :Color node.

Results:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"result"                                                              │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"name":"a","color":"black"},{"name":"b","color":"blue"},{"name":"d",│
│"color":"black"}]                                                     │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{"name":"a","color":"black"},{"name":"c","color":"blue"}]            │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you a lot your answer perfectly answers my question, even more generic than I wished for, but that is even better, as I now understand more about cypher.